# LINQ TO ENTITY: Removing special characters inside the "where" expression

Tags: c#, string, linq, entity-framework

I am usins LINQ TO ENTITY in order to filter a list of persons based on their phone number.

```
IEnumerable<Person> personsList = (from person in repoPersons.All()
                                             where person.PhoneNumber.Contains(PhoneSearch)
                                             select person).ToList();
```

`repoPersons.All()` contains all the persons read from the database.
`PhoneSearch` is the search term entered by the user.

The Phone number is saved in the database as a string in a special format: `+1 (555) 555-6608` (as an example.

But I want to allow the user to search for `5555556608` without having to format it properly. (I want him to be able to search for part of the phone number too like `556608` and still get the result.

I tried to create a Method called  `RemoveSpecialCharactersInPhoneNumber` that will remove the special characters and returns it and use it like this:

```
IEnumerable<Person> personsList = (from person in repoPersons.All()
                                             where RemoveSpecialCharactersInPhoneNumber(person.PhoneNumber).Contains(PhoneSearch)
                                             select person).ToList();
```

But I get this error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String RemoveSpecialCharactersInPhoneNumber(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a person expression.
```

So is there a way I can check if the PhoneNumber contains PhoneSearch without the special character, using LINQ TO ENTITY?

I know I can use LINQ TO ENTITY to get all the list and then use LINQ TO OBJECT to filter it but I am trying to avoid this approach.

Any solution or hint is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following isn't exactly neat and tidy, but it will solve your problem (as no method is trying to be incorrectly resolved on the SQL end)

```
IEnumerable<Person> personsList = (from person in repoPersons.All()
         where person.Phone.Replace("+", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "").Contains(PhoneNumber)
         select person).ToList()
```

Comment: It would be nice if it was possible to make an extension method to resolve this replace repetition. Is that possible?

Comment: @JoseGuilhermeMonteiro A little late, but the answer is yes.

Comment: Extension does not working, I try it and it through error

Answer (score 1):

It will give error because the linq to entity will be converted into SQL query so there is no method for RemoveSpecialCharactersInPhoneNumber in sql.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/19a33909-c532-419b-a533-57e431c0b30b) is similar question.

Seems like as where clause is evaluated on server side, this method cannot be recognized.

CLR method needs to be converted to [Cannonical mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx) so that it can be executed on server.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing

```
IEnumerable<Person> personsList = (from person in repoPersons.All().ToList()
                                         where RemoveSpecialCharactersInPhoneNumber(person.PhoneNumber).Contains(PhoneSearch)
                                         select person).ToList();
```

This will prevent LINQ from trying to resolve `RemoveSpecialCharactersInPhoneNumber` in the SQL layer, and instead it can be processed by your business layer as you described.

Comment: yes this will load everything in the memory. it will be like converting it to LINQ TO OBJECT, something I want to avoid. Thanks